# How To Debug Web API Project From MVC Project In Another Solution

Tags: api, debugging, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC project solution and a separate API project solution (because it is used by different other solutions).

During debugging is it possible to hit the API solution code on debugging?

Both solutions are obviously running, giving correct data and results, the issue is that I am unable to hit the API project code during debugging - the debugger skips over the API and hits only the main solution.

**EDIT**
I realised that the API is a separate package and is referenced in the main solution as an assembly so I am not sure if it is possible to hit the breakpoint there at all? It's not used via Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

yeah it is possible.

Assuming you use Visual Studio, start a second instance and attach it to the running process of the API. Put a breakpoint in your API and do whatever you need on the MVC side, to hit the correct endpoint in the API. Execution will stop and you can now debug in the second project as well.

This all depends how you run the API, you can even run the API from Visual Studio, using IIS Express in which case your URL will look something like `http:\\localhost\api\sbla\bla:50310` for example.

Attaching works very well when the API is run outside of Visual Studio in proper IIS.
Make sure you tick the box which says "Show all processes" and look for a process called w3wp I think, this is all from memory.

You can't debug the API from the MVC project as they are both running under different processes

------ added after extra info ----

if the API stuff is inside a dll then make sure that dll is built in debug mode and then you can step into it. put a break point inside your MVC code right before you have a call which goes into the dll, then step into it and continue from there with normal debugging

Comment: That's what I did but I found out that the API is actually referenced as another assembly, it is not used via ajax - see my edit above @Andrei

Comment: added more info to deal with the new info.

Comment: That's the case - I can't step into it, it steps over whenever I try to step in.

Comment: is the dll built in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Just open both your solutions in visual studio. Build the API project and add its dll to MVC project. Put break point on your API and run the API project. Now run your MVC project. Hit the API from your MVC project and break point will surely hit in API.